# Having trouble querying USER_OBJECTS in Oracle/ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, plsql, odp.net

I'm trying to create an Entity Framework model based on `USER_OBJECTS` so that I can query the inventory of packages & procedures.  It looks like calls to `USER_OBJECTS` must be schema-less, but I can't figure out a way to configure entity / dbcontext to generate a statement without a schema.

1)  Is there a special schema prefix that `USER_OBJECTS` can be called under?

2)  If not, then how can I get Entity Framework to drop the schema prefix from the generated statements?

I have found that if I don't provide a schema, it defaults to the executing user, and I get the handy `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` error.

If I provide a blank string, it defaults to `dbo` which isn't helpful at all in Oracle.

**Empty String for Schema Method**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
   ... CODE TRUNCATED FOR READABILITY ...
   Dim entityConfig = entityMethodGeneric.Invoke(modelBuilder, Nothing)
   Dim toTableMethod = entityConfig.[GetType]().GetMethod("ToTable", New Type() {GetType(String), GetType(String)})

   toTableMethod.Invoke(entityConfig, New Object() {"USER_OBJECTS", ""})

   MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
End Sub
```

**Yields**

```
SELECT   "Extent1"."OBJECT_ID" AS "OBJECT_ID"
     ,   "Extent1"."OBJECT_TYPE" AS "OBJECT_TYPE"
     ,   "Extent1"."OBJECT_NAME" AS "OBJECT_NAME"
     ,   "Extent1"."STATUS" AS "STATUS"  

FROM "dbo"."USER_OBJECTS" "Extent1"  

WHERE (("Extent1"."OBJECT_NAME" = :p__linq__0) AND ('PACKAGE' = "Extent1"."OBJECT_TYPE"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can query `USER_OBJECTS` against the `SYS` schema, so I just wired up my entity to use that schema for the necessary tables.

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.USER_OBJECTS
```